# Pull and store value from a specific column/row for many dataframes? (using dplyr, ideally)

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, data-extraction

I'm attempting to store specific values as an object in my global environment (to use later in plotting).

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame (spp  = c("spp1", "spp2", "spp3", "spp4","spp1", "spp2", "spp3", "spp4"),
                  v1 = c("2", "4", "6", "8", "9", "3", "4", "5"),
                  v2 = c(".6", ".8", ".9", ".65", ".7", ".8", ".5", ".3")
)
```

Code so far:

(Step 1)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(spp) %>% 
  summarise(max_v1 = max(v1), 
            max_v2 = max(v2)) %>% 
  group_split(spp) %>% 
  setNames(unique(df$spp)) %>%
  list2env(envir = globalenv())
```

...resulting in 4 dataframes (1 per spp) each with 3 columns and 1 row.

Now I'd like to extract "max_v1" and "max_v2" for each species and store it as a single value in my environment, resulting in 8 new values that I can then use later on. I can do it individually like this:

(Step 2)

```
spp1_max_v1 <- spp1 %>% select(max_v1) %>% pull()
spp1_max_v2 <- spp1 %>% select(max_v2) %>% pull()
```

But, given that my actual dataset has many species, I'd like to iterate the process. What is the best way to do this? I'd like to stick with dplyr, if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in separate objects.  It may be easier to keep it in the data.frame and use it later i.e. `out <- df %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% group_by(spp) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), max, .names = "max_{.col}"))`

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following code after your own code block above, you will get the desired result:

```r
lapply(mget(paste0("spp", 1:4)), function(x) {
  assign(paste0(x$spp,"_max_v1"), x$max_v1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  assign(paste0(x$spp,"_max_v2"), x$max_v2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
```

[image]

However, as @akrun points out, this isn't a great idea. In general, if you can keep your data in a list or data frame rather than polluting your global environment, this is far better (note that the very first thing the above code has to do is reassemble the list of data frames that you just wrote into the global environment so that we could iterate on them - we could have skipped two lines of code by not writing to the global environment at all)